# How to use xdebug to remotely debug a php script hosted on a vmware

Tags: php, vmware, xdebug, zend-studio

I'm having a really annoying problem. I use ZendStudio as a php IDE and I need to be able to debug an application which is deployed in a couple of servers:

- A fisical server
- A virtual server (vmware) hosted on my local machine

Both servers run CenOs, my local machine is running LinuxMint.

I configured the application so that when I save a file it is automatically uploaded to my virtual server.

The php configuration is the same in both servers, but, I can only debug using the fisical server.

I have tried several things including:

- Changing the IP of the remote host to match every posible ip address for the host machine (vmware gives me two new ip addresses matching the subnet of the vm)
- Activating xdebug.remote_connect_back
- Activating xdebug.remote_autostart
- Trying ZendDebugger

Nothing seemed to work.

I disabled ufw and eventually allowed port 9000.

Help please! :)

**Edit:**

I just created a new environment like this:

- Fisical machine Ubuntu 10.10
- VM LinuxMint 10 with apache+php+xdebug

From my fisical machine I created a new remote project pointing to the VM, created a test script, run the debugger and it worked! right out of the box... now, I'm not sure this is good or bad news, since I need to get this working with the CentOs... any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: News on this: today I created a whole new vm using the same Linux Mint from the host in the vm and still couldn't get it to connect. I tried switching from a NAT connection to a bridged one (configured gateway and dns, surfed the web and stuff), but couldn't get connected... will keep trying.

Comment: Ok, just in case anybody is still reading this. My newest updates: I just switched the vm to bridged mode, setup a remote zendstudio project on my co-worker's machine and uploaded a simple script into my vm, then I try to run a debugging session but got the same results as I got so far... this is getting kind of painful... I guess my next move will be to try again from the same machine I use, only booting it with Ubuntu and see what happens...

Comment: Hi: I just tested my latest approach. Booted back the system with a regular Ubuntu 11.04, set up the project and tried to remotely debug against the VM, which completely failed... I'm running out of ideas :(

Comment: Hey: It's me again! At least no one can say I give up easy!. Anyway, my latest attempt was to install VMWare Workstation instead of VMWare Player, but still, no luck

Comment: Hey!!! Finally I came up with an acceptable solution! I switched from VMWare to VirtualBox, just converted a previous vmware vm into a vb one, had to setup a host-only network (don't really know why), and it just worked! So, I guess this will be my last post on this subject. Thanks!

Comment: Well, it seems I was wrong after all :(. I just realized I can debug just fine from Mint-to-Mint, but I can't debug from Mint-CentOs, which is actually what I need to achieve...

Comment: It's me again. Still looking for it. My new finding: the local connection is listening for clients on tcp6::9000 which is apparently not the one I need, but tcp::9000. Still don't have the answer, but I think I'm getting there.

Comment: you need to setup the interface properly in "Virtual Network Editor" - it needs to have an own IP, with a netmask which matches the rest of the segment - then one can connect to xdebug via IP, just as if would be a stand-alone physical machine. be sure to enable remote debugging in the config file (there's a few parameters in there relating to remote debug).